# How to display all the columns (and their type) in all tables of all schemas in a database?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose you have a database which has an 'n' number of schemas with an 'n' number of tables each. Each of these contain an 'n' number of columns.
How would I print all this data along with the data type used in the columns. I need to make a consolidated list for reference purposes and I really don't want to desc each table individually.
What I have already used:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OWNER = '*Schema_Name*';
```

and then

```
SELECT utc.TABLE_NAME ,
   utc.COLUMN_NAME ,
   utc.DATA_TYPE
   FROM  USER_TAB_COLUMNS utc
   WHERE utc.TABLE_NAME ='*Table Name*';
```

However this reduces the effort but still makes things tiresome considering the volume of data I have to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a data model. You tagged SQL Developer, so I'm considering that's available for the solution.

You say 'ALL SCHEMAS', but I'm assuming you mean all of your application schemas, not users or oracle internal ones.

Once you have the model, you have your choice of diagrams, html, pdf, and Excel for display.

You just need to reverse engineer the schemas to a model, and then publish.

[How to RE an existing schema or schemas](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/10/importing-multiple-schemas-to-a-model-in-oracle-sql-developer-data-modeler/)

[image]

For a ton of objects - in the thousands, you'll want to increase the amount of memory for your jvm to 3 GB or so for an optimal experience.

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a good method and the result is particularly useful. However, it is extremely time consuming. Should that be happening?
Please note that I have an incredibly large volume of data and the generation of a single data model has been going on for nearly an hour now. I think this answer is perfect for a detailed analysis. For just a list the query below works well.

Comment: Depends on how big - like I said, if you're dealing with a LOT of information, then bump your jvm to 3 or even 4 GB. Go with the simplest solution - if the query below meets your needs, much faster. But, if you get that data and then want to start asking more questions...it will lead back to a proper data model. And the diagram will be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

For this you require DBA Access or atleast select query access to the schemas and tables that you require.

```
select owner,table_name,column_name,data_type from dba_tab_cols order by owner;
```

is the query that will provide you all the schemas along with all the tables and their columns and data types. If you want to customise your query to suit any schema or table for data.